# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel - access current index

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get the current index from the carousel?

In this case I am using an unordered list. I know I could search through the list items to find the one with the 'active' CSS class, but I want to know if I can ask the carousel object directly.

Additional: being able to access the target index (on 'slide' event) would be handy also. Again, I can do this by searching with:

```
var idx = $('.carousel-inner li.active').index();
```

...and then adding/subtracting based on direction, but I am hoping for something cleaner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to access index or direction.

[See here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229)

// EDIT

Bootstrap changed repos, new [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229)

Comment: This link suggests `$(".active", e.target).index()` which seems to work well.

Comment: "Page not found" on your link

Answer (score 74):

Instead of adding and subtracting from the current slide, try this on the 'slide' event:

```
$('.carousel').on('slide',function(e){
    var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
    var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    console.log(slideFrom+' => '+slideTo);
});
```

Comment: This should really be the answer.

Comment: In Bootstrap 3.0+ the event is catched like this: `$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  // do something…
})`

Comment: In Boostrap 3.0+, just like `$(e.relatedTarget).index();`, how can I find the previous target? Meaning the current index -1?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me (Bootstrap 3)

```
$("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(evt) {
  console.debug("slide transition started")
  console.debug('current slide = ', $(this).find('.active').index())
  console.debug('next slide = ', $(evt.relatedTarget).index())
})
```

Comment: worked best with Bootstrap 4 also in mid April, 2020

Answer (score 20):

It appears Bootstrap 4 finally has the native implementation of this.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21668

```js
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e){
  e.direction     // The direction in which the carousel is sliding (either "left" or "right").
  e.relatedTarget // The DOM element that is being slid into place as the active item.
  e.from          // The index of the current item.     
  e.to            // The index of the next item.
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 11):

`$(".active", e.target).index()` works. Where e from:

```
carousel.on("slid", function (e) {
   $(".active", e.target).index();
});
```

Found on: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229

Answer (score 11):

For bootstrap 3 it's

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var active = $(e.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
  var from = active.index();
  var next = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var to = next.index();
  console.log(from + ' => ' + to);
})
```

from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-22362366

Comment: Short version would be: var to = $(e.relatedTarget).index()

Answer (score 7):

I'm doing it like that, that works sort of very well ;)

```
var slider = $("#slider-wrapper")
    .carousel({
        interval: 4000
    })
    .bind('slid', function() {
        var index = $(this).find(".active").index();
        $(this).find("a").removeClass('pager-active').eq(index).addClass('pager-active');
    });

$("#slider-wrapper a").click(function(e){
    var index = $(this).index();
    slider.carousel(index);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to access the slide index using a jquery function from the bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
    alert(event.from);
   // You can use use 'event.from' in whatever way works best for you here
}
```

`.from` on the event will give you the slide where the slide instance occurs. `.to` will give you the slide where the slide instance is going to. Using `slide.bs.carousel` will execute the function before the slide animation, `slid.bs.carousel` will execute the function after the slide animation but the returned slide number will be the same.

There's a few other properties that the `slide` and `slid` events give you access to, I recommend checking them out on the carousel documentation page.

Note: I am using bootstrap 4.3.1.

Comment: actual solution that works out of the box. no need for complex queries

Comment: excellent solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with after reading fat's comment in @Quelltextfabrik's answer.

```
var carousel = $("#myCarousel");

carousel.on("slid", function () {
    var all = carousel.find('.item'),
        active = carousel.find('.active'),
        slidTo = all.index(active);

    console.log("Slid - Slid To: " + slidTo);
    });

carousel.on("slide", function () {
    var all = carousel.find('.item'),
        active = carousel.find('.active'),
        slidFrom = all.index(active);

    console.log("Slide - Slid From: " + slidFrom);
});
```

Comment: To work in boostrap 3.0.3, I had to modify the event names:

slid -> slid.bs.carousel ; and slide -> slide.bs.carousel

Comment: This does not work for Bootstrap 4.1.3.What changes would be necessary for it to work?