# Bootstrap AngularJS carousel - how to know the active slide object

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way I can know what is the current active slide?

```js
var slides = slides = []; 
slides.push({text: 'Slide 1', type: "chart", chartConfig : { 
                    options: {chart: {type: 'bar'}}, 
                    series: [{data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]}], 
                    title: {text: 'Hello 1'}, 
                    loading: false 
}}); 
slides.push({text: 'Slide 3', type: "chart", chartConfig : { 
                            options: {chart: {type: 'bar'}}, 
                    series: [{data: [10, 35, 52, 8, 7]}], 
                    title: {text: 'Hello 2'}, 
                    loading: false 
}}); 
$scope.slides=slides;
```

```html
<carousel> 
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides"> 
        <highchart id="chart{{$index}}" config="slide.chartConfig"></highchart> 
    </slide> 
</carousel>
```

I am not sure were i need to add watch though?

Please treat this as a seperate question:

You can see from my code there are 2 charts information in the slide.
But when its presented / slided second one alone gets squeezed in width.

In other words is there any way i can auto scale the highchart at the time of rendering?

Is there any work around to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**:

Actually, `angular-ui` does allow you to set an `active` property on the `slide` directive which will be set to true when the slide becomes active.

In this example: `slide.active` will be set to `true` when the slide is active.

```html
<carousel> 
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active"> 
        <highchart id="chart{{$index}}" config="slide.chartConfig"></highchart> 
    </slide> 
</carousel>
```

**Controller**

```js
var slides = slides = []; 

slides.push({
    active: false
  , text: 'Slide 1'
  , type: "chart"
  , chartConfig : { 
        options: {chart: {type: 'bar'}}, 
        series: [{data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]}], 
        title: {text: 'Hello 1'}, 
        loading: false }
    }
); 

slides.push({
    active: false
  , text: 'Slide 3'
  , type: "chart"
  , chartConfig : { 
        options: {chart: {type: 'bar'}}, 
        series: [{data: [10, 35, 52, 8, 7]}], 
        title: {text: 'Hello 2'}, 
        loading: false }
   }
); 

$scope.slides=slides;

// May return `undefined` if no slide is active 
// (e.g. when the carousel hasn't initialised)
$scope.getActiveSlide = function () {
    return slides.filter(function (s) { return s.active; })[0];
};
```

---

There [was an issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-22362366) to add this information to the `slide` event, but they decided not to do it.

There are some workarounds to it though:

1. [This comment on the issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-22362366)
2. [Twitter Bootstrap Carousel - access current index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860436/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-access-current-index)

Comment: This is perfect exact answer i was looking for.

Comment: Please treat this as a seperate question:

You can see from my code there are 2 charts information in the slide. But when its presented / slided second one alone gets squeezed in width.

In other words is there any way i can auto scale the highchart at the time of rendering?

Is there any work around to fix it.

Kind Regards Kay

Comment: I would recommend creating a separate question for it, in that case.

Comment: @musically_ut Hi good solution, but in version doesn't work anymore, maybe there is different solution for new version?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get the current index of the carousel slide with the following jQuery code (the carousel html must have the `id="myCarousel"`):

```
$('#myCarousel .active').index();
```

I used it for adding the ng-swipe-left/right to the carousel and it works (if you are interesed, full answer with the controller js code here: [angular ui.bootstrap.carousel call next()/prev() from $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562352/angular-ui-bootstrap-carousel-call-next-prev-from-scope/22730482#22730482))

It works for bootstrap 3.0.2