# Bootstrap Carousel: Caption above the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put the caption of Bootstrap Carousel above the content.
It works actually but not properly. If you click on the chevrons you'll see `< Item 1 >` bouncing... **(<= This is the bug and if you're logic you understand the expected behavior with my sentence "How to fix that?")**

**Demo:** [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6IDwOaFiFl)

**This is the minimal code : 1 carousel with 3 slides / 2 lines of CSS to make it work / JS to make it work**

I think it's due the relative positioning but I don't want to put an absolute position.

This solution helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24607364/6132061

How to fix that? Thank you <3

Comment: This is already the minimal code. Blah blah blah.

Comment: There is no code here. You should fix that. Links don't count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the fadeOut() and fadeIn() effects duration to zero:

```
$('.liens-bonus-caption:not(#liens-bonus-'+step+')').fadeOut(0, function() {
            $('#liens-bonus-'+step).fadeIn(0);
});
```

Otherwise the animation in between will be displayed resulting in a "bouncy" element.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :) **Demo:** [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dAMidf8a2s) if someone look at this.