# carousel caption based on url hash

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, hash, carousel, window.location

I'm very new to coding, so apologies if my terminology is inaccurate. I built a site with a bootstrap carousel. I wanted the caption to display in a separate column. I found this nifty code to do that:

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
var caption = $('div.item:nth-child(1) .carousel-caption');
$('#right').html(caption.html());
caption.css('display','none');
$(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(evt) {

    var caption = $('div.item:nth-child(' + ($(evt.relatedTarget).index()+1) + ') .carousel-caption');
    $('#right').html(caption.html());
    caption.css('display','none');
});
```

Thanks to folks here for the code: [How to place Bootstrap Carousel image captions outside the carousel div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437925/how-to-place-bootstrap-carousel-image-captions-outside-the-carousel-div)

I then display the caption in the location I want with a simple:

```
<p id="right"></p>
```

My issue is that I'm also appending a #hash to the URL so that I can target specific items in the carousel from other pages on my site (e.g, item four has the url www.mysite.com#4 so that I can link to that specific item). The code that appends the hash also sets the item as active. For reference, it is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var url = document.location.toString();
    var totalItems = $('.item').length;

    //Initiate carousel
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    })

    $('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

        var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

        //Update pager-text
        $('.pager-text').text(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

        // Update location based on slide (index is 0-based)
        window.location.hash = "#"+ parseInt($('.carousel .carousel-inner .item.active').index()+1);
    });


    if (url.match('#')) {
        // Clear active item
        $('.carousel .carousel-inner .item.active').removeClass('active');

        // Activate item number #hash
        $('.carousel-inner div:nth-child(' + url.split('#')[1] + ')').addClass('active');

        //Update pager-text
        $('.pager-text').text(''+url.split('#')[1]+'/'+totalItems+'');

    }

});
```

h/t here: [Update the current number of slide when jumping to specific item - Bootstrap 3 Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093612/update-the-current-number-of-slide-when-jumping-to-specific-item-bootstrap-3-c)

However, **the caption always matches the first item in the carousel list** (which is the only one that has class="item active" in the html, otherwise the carousel will not display). How do I get the page to **display the caption for the specific URL hash I want to target**? For example, if I want it to match the caption for the carousel item at: www.myurl.com#4

Thank you! I'm happy to share all the code in github once it's done so others can use this.

Comment: One note here: the caption is correct when I cycle through the carousel. It finds the correct item and displays the correct caption. It's when I click from another page, I see the correct photo, but the caption is always the first in the series. Once I hit next/previous, the caption updates to the correct one. So it's only when I arrive on the page via clicking a reference URL (for instance, when I click into <a href="www.mysite.com#4">photo</a> it goes to the correct photo, but the caption is wrong).

Comment: can you please create fiddle or bootply example for your code, to understand it better. thanks.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sam887/pzkmurbf/

Could not get it to display properly in fiddle, but the code works locally.