# Unable to select the children of the next bootstrap carousel slide?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to to get id of the image of the carousel that will be the active item. That is I am trying to get of the image id of the slide event. Currently, I have:

```
function ModalImageCaption () {
   var activeImage =
   $('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event){
       var imageId = $(event.relatedTarget).find('.carousel-inner');
       console.log (imageId);
   });
}
```

The console log implies that there are children nodes one of them being the image child so I update imageId variable to

```
var imageId=$(event.relatedTarget).find('.carousel-inner').children('img').attr('id');
```

but it always comes back as undefined is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do:

```
$('.gallery-carousel').data("bs.carousel").getActiveIndex()
```

or

```
getItemIndex()
```

after 3.2

from:

[Twitter Bootstrap Carousel - access current index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860436/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-access-current-index)

And:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229

Comment: No, unfortunately that did not work for me. I tired the direct copy and paste version of your suggestion, then I tried different variations of it. Even if it did I don't think it would have gotten the correct slide as the active slide as far as I can tell doesn't change until the very end of the event. Whereas I trying to get the slide that will soon to be active.

Comment: Did you try all solution from github website given? like this.
$(".carousel").on('slid', function(e){ 
$(".active", e.target).index()})